# jQuery Validation giving error with every character entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validator on a form on my site. It is functioning properly, but every keystroke results in an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'call'
```

I am implementing validation through classes on each field and all that is working properly - required fields, email fields, numbers, etc.. Here is my validate code:

```
 if(jQuery().validate) {
      //assign to global var for manual validation
      validator = $(".validated").validate({
           errorClass: "help-inline text-error",
           errorElement: "span",
           invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
                var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                if (errors) {
                     var message = errors == 1
                          ? 'Please fix the indicated field before saving this form.'
                          : 'Please fix the errors on the indicated fields before saving this form.';
                      $(".validation-message").text(message);
                      $(".validation-message").addClass('alert alert-error');
                } else {
                      $(".validation-message").removeClass('alert alert-error').text("");
                }
             },
           onkeyup: true,
           submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(".validation-message").removeClass('alert alert-error').text("");
                form.submit();
             },
           errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if(element.parent().hasClass('input-append')){
                     error.insertAfter( element.parent() );
                }else{
                     error.insertAfter(element);
                }
             }
      });
 }
```

Can anyone see what would trigger that error without impacting functionality?

Cheers!

Comment: The `onkeyup` option is what's causing this.

Comment: Yes.. that is what's causing it to happen on keystroke, but the error is still happening.....

Comment: Ah.. yes I see.. the true is not a valid value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `true` value for `onkeyup` option.

By default the field validation is enabled during `keyup` event. You need to use this option only in two scenarios

1. To disable validation during `keyup` event, in that case set `onkeyup: false`
2. To customize field validation during `keyup`

In your case you can just remove the option `onkeyup`.

Comment: Ahh.. yes, thanks. I set it to false while testing, now I see that I was wrong to set it to true to re-enable it.